# Beamer: want to insert a minimal second title page with title only

Tags: beamer, titles

I have the main title page and a second one. On the second one I just want the title only to appear. I don't want the following two lines to appear:

Supervisor1: Supervisor1 Name1
Supervisor2: Supervisor2 Name2

Here at the bottom is the picture according to what I get now.[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage {textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bbding} %Checkmark
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlegraphicii[1]{\def\inserttitlegraphicii{#1}}
\titlegraphicii{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\hfill\inserttitlegraphicii\par}
        \begin{centering}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
                \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
                \else%
                    \vskip0.25em%
                    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
                \fi%     
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \vskip1em\par
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
                \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{supervisors}
                \usebeamerfont{institute}
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{8pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
                        Supervisor1: & Supervisor1 Name$^1$ \\
                        Supervisor2: & Supervisor2 Name$^2$
                    \end{tabular}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute1}
                \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            %\footnotesize
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
                \footnotesize\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
            \end{beamercolorbox}%\vskip0.5em
        \end{centering}
        %\vfill
}
\makeatother
\author{{\small{by:}} Author Name$^1$}
\title[Short title]{Long title}
\institute{$^1$Department University1 \\ $^2$Department University2}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Insertion numéros de page et courte version du titre
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \title[Short title]{Long title}

    \date{}
    \author{}
    \author{}
    \institute{}

    \begin{frame}\frametitle{}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution, just set the colour `\setbeamercolor{supervisors}{fg=white}` to white:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage {textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bbding} %Checkmark
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlegraphicii[1]{\def\inserttitlegraphicii{#1}}
\titlegraphicii{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\hfill\inserttitlegraphicii\par}
        \begin{centering}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
                \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
                \else%
                    \vskip0.25em%
                    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
                \fi%     
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \vskip1em\par
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
                \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{supervisors}
                \usebeamerfont{institute}
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{8pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
                        Supervisor1: & Supervisor1 Name$^1$ \\
                        Supervisor2: & Supervisor2 Name$^2$
                    \end{tabular}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute1}
                \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            %\footnotesize
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
                \footnotesize\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
            \end{beamercolorbox}%\vskip0.5em
        \end{centering}
        %\vfill
}
\makeatother
\author{{\small{by:}} Author Name$^1$}
\title[Short title]{Long title}
\institute{$^1$Department University1 \\ $^2$Department University2}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Insertion numéros de page et courte version du titre
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \title[Short title]{Long title}
    \setbeamercolor{supervisors}{fg=white}

    \date{}
    \author{}
    \author{}
    \institute{}

    \begin{frame}\frametitle{}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]